# Matrix exponential theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponentiation, matrix-exponential

I have difficulties in demonstrating the following theorem

For all  $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $P\in GL\left ( \mathbb{R}^{n} \right )$ . Then  $e^{PAP^{-1}}=Pe^{A}P^{-1}$

I saw that the proof of this theorem begins

For $k\geq 0$, $P\left (\sum_{j=0}^{m} \frac{1}{j!}A^{j} \right )P^{-1}=\sum_{j=0}^{m}\frac{1}{j!}\left ( PA^{j}P^{-1} \right )=\sum_{j=0}^{m}\frac{1}{j!}\left ( PAP^{-1} \right )^{j}$

then taking the limit when $m\rightarrow \infty $ to both members of the equality, the theorem is tested

If you consider that $\left ( AB \right )^{j}=A^{j}B^{j}$,$\forall j\in \mathbb{N}$. Then $\left ( PAP^{-1} \right )^{j}=P^{j}A^{j}P^{-j}$,which implies that $PA^{j}P^{-1}\neq \left ( PAP^{-1} \right )^{j}$. Then $e^{PAP^{-1}}\neq Pe^{A}P^{-1}$.

I think it is not the demonstration process or missing data to the theorem. I would like you to clarify me please.
Thank you for your help

Comment: For matricies $\left ( AB \right )^{j}= \underbrace{ABAB \cdots AB}_{j \text { 
 times}} \neq A^{j}B^{j}
$

Comment: And $(PAP^{-1})^j = \underbrace{PAP^{-1} \cdot PAP^{-1} \cdot \dots \cdot PAP^{-1}}_{j\, { times}} = P A^j P^{-1}$

Answer (score 2):

In general, matrices don't commute.

On the other hand,\begin{align}(PAP^{-1})^2&=PA\overbrace{P^{-1}P}^{=\operatorname{Id}}AP^{-1}=PAAP^{-1}=PA^2P^{-1},\\(PAP^{-1})^3&=PA\overbrace{P^{-1}P}^{=\operatorname{Id}}A\overbrace{P^{-1}P}^{=\operatorname{Id}}AP^{-1}=PAAAP^{-1}=PA^3P^{-1},\end{align}and so on.